# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).combobox is not a function

Tags: php, html, jquery, codeigniter, combobox

I have got the Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in this line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/usser_assets/css/bootstrap-combobox.css" type="text/css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/usser_assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" >

    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

         <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/usser_assets/js/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.combobox').combobox()
    });
</script>
```

AND

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <select class="form-control data-search-field combobox"  >
                                    <option value="">Select Tyre Brand</option>
                                    <?php foreach ($tyre_model_list as $row) {

                                       ?> 
                                   <option value="<?php echo $row->tyre_brand_id;?>"><?php echo $row->name;?></option>
                                    <?php }?>
                                </select>


                            </div>
```

What does it mean? The combobox is filled correctly. What is wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that bootstrap-combobox.js might not be getting loaded, chech in the web inspector tools in your browser in the network tab

Comment: its loaded but combobox is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for me, I don't get any error:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.combobox').combobox()
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.2.0/css/bootstrap-combobox.min.css" type="text/css" >
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-combobox/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-combobox.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <select class="form-control data-search-field combobox"  >
        <option value="">Select Tyre Brand</option>
       <option value="option1">option 1</option>
       <option value="option2">option 2</option>
       <option value="option3">option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```